# HTML Table code is breaking my DIV order

Tags: css, html-table

I am restating this question entirely.  I had to design a whole page to show this.

The Gallery DIV is suppose to show up next to the Events DIV, but when I put TABLE into the kevin.php, it moves the Gallery DIV into the kevin2 div.  I remove TABLE, it goes back to the way it should.

What am I doing wrong?

index.php

```
<head>
<TITLE>example page</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="events">
<h2>Events</h2>
</div>
    <div class="eventsmenu">
        <div class ="kevin">
            <b>Kevin's Kleanup</b>
        </div>
        <div class ="shady">
            <b>Shady Sweep</b>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
$( ".events" ).click(function() {
  $( ".eventsmenu" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>

    <div class="kevin2"><?php include("kevin.php"); ?></div>
    <div class="shady2"><?php include("shady.php"); ?></div>

<script>
$( ".kevin" ).click(function() {
  $( ".kevin2" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
$( ".shady" ).click(function() {
  $( ".shady2" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>

<div class="gallery">
<h2>Gallery</h2>
</div>
    <div class="gallery2">
        <div class="galclose">
        <h4>Close Window</h4>
        </div>
        <script>
        $( ".galclose" ).click(function() {
          $( ".gallery2" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
        });
        </script>
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:900px;border:3px black;" src="gallery.php"></iframe>
    </div>
<script>
$( ".gallery" ).click(function() {
  $( ".gallery2" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>

</body>
```

kevin.php

```
<div class="kevinclose">
<h4>Close Window</h4>
</div>
<script>
$( ".kevinclose" ).click(function() {
  $( ".kevin2" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
  $( ".eventsmenu" ).slideToggle( "fast" );
});
</script>

<h2><i>2014</i></h2>
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td>Overall Results</td>
    <td>Class Results</td>
    <td>Participants</td>
    <td>Number</td>
    <td>Class</td>
    <td>Overall Time</td>
</tr>
```

some.css

```
    body {
  color: #000000;
  background: #7af8f7; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    left top,
    #009ad2,
    #7af8f7
  ); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    bottom right,
    #009ad2,
    #7af8f7
  ); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    bottom right,
    #009AD2F,
    #7af8f7
  ); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom right,
    #009ad2,
    #7af8f7
  ); /* Standard syntax */
}

.events {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #009ad2;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
.eventsmenu {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -150px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #7af8f7;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.kevin2 {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #009ad2;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.kevinclose {
  background-color: #7af8f7;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  line-height: 2%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.shady2 {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #009ad2;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.shadyclose {
  background-color: #7af8f7;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  line-height: 2%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.gallery {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #009ad2;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
.gallery2 {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #009ad2;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
iframe {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.galclose {
  background-color: #7af8f7;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  line-height: 2%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

shady.php

```
<h1>Shady</h1>
```

gallery.php

```
<h1>Gallery</h1>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is not well formatted, you have no closing `</table>`. The correct syntax is:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Body1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Foot1</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Since you do not close the table, than browser has to figure out where it ends. That is why you have a broken layout.

Additional data we can see [here](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#Browsers_error_tolerance) says what happens if the element is not closed and browser hits some other element (not in place):

> The element being added is explicitly forbidden inside some outer tag.
>   In this case we should close all tags up to the one, which forbids the
>   element, and add it afterwards.

But since the next element is `<div class="shady2">` and it is not forbidden inside the table, than browser renders it as a part of the opened table.